# AngularJS coverting to HTTPS. Getting errors and Angular won't load

Tags: angularjs, https, zurb-foundation

I'm reviving an old project written in AngularJS for Foundation. I decided to add HTTPS. I've got the domain it's on properly secured and I've Find/Replaced all http: with https:

However, it now shows this error in Chrome console when loading the page:

```
foundation.js:5346 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $httpProvider <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state

  at foundation.js:5346
    at foundation.js:9659
    at Object.getService [as get] (foundation.js:9807)
    at foundation.js:9664
    at getService (foundation.js:9807)
    at invoke (foundation.js:9839)
    at Object.instantiate (foundation.js:9856)
    at Object.<anonymous> (foundation.js:9716)
    at Object.invoke (foundation.js:9848)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (foundation.js:9700)
```

Any idea why? My guess is the $http call, but angular doesn't offer something specifically for https. Again, this error is only present when I force the domain to use https.

Here's foundation.js:5346:

```
return new ErrorConstructor(message);
```

:9659-9664

```
}

return {
  invoke: invoke,
  instantiate: instantiate,
  get: getService,
```

:9700-9716

```
   var result = instanceInjector.invoke(factory, this);
      if (isUndefined(result)) {
        throw $injectorMinErr('undef', "Provider '{0}' must return a value from $get factory method.", name);
      }
      return result;
    };
  }

  function factory(name, factoryFn, enforce) {
    return provider(name, {
      $get: enforce !== false ? enforceReturnValue(name, factoryFn) : factoryFn
    });
  }

  function service(name, constructor) {
    return factory(name, ['$injector', function($injector) {
      return $injector.instantiate(constructor);
```

:9807-9856

```
 return cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName, caller);
} catch (err) {
  if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
    delete cache[serviceName];
  }
  throw err;
} finally {
  path.shift();
}


 }
}

function invoke(fn, self, locals, serviceName) {
  if (typeof locals === 'string') {
    serviceName = locals;
    locals = null;
  }

  var args = [],
      $inject = createInjector.$$annotate(fn, strictDi, serviceName),
      length, i,
      key;

  for (i = 0, length = $inject.length; i < length; i++) {
    key = $inject[i];
    if (typeof key !== 'string') {
      throw $injectorMinErr('itkn',
              'Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got {0}', key);
    }
    args.push(
      locals && locals.hasOwnProperty(key)
      ? locals[key]
      : getService(key, serviceName)
    );
  }
  if (isArray(fn)) {
    fn = fn[length];
  }

  // http://jsperf.com/angularjs-invoke-apply-vs-switch
  // #5388
  return fn.apply(self, args);
}

function instantiate(Type, locals, serviceName) {
  // Check if Type is annotated and use just the given function at n-1 as parameter
  // e.g. someModule.factory('greeter', ['$window', function(renamed$window) {}]);
  // Object creation: http://jsperf.com/create-constructor/2
  var instance = Object.create((isArray(Type) ? Type[Type.length - 1] : Type).prototype || null);
  var returnedValue = invoke(Type, instance, locals, serviceName);
```

**Update:** Well, that was easy. It had been awhile since I worked on this. It was 100% foundation.js and my custom code was elsewhere. I replaced the foundation.js with the original, that hadn't replaced http with https and it all worked fine.

Comment: Could you show us the lines of code where this error is occurring? This is a fairly generic error, but it most likely means you haven't properly configured your dependency injection for $httpProvider somewhere. You may have accidentally changed your code with the find/replace all. (Assuming everything worked before changing to HTTPS)

Comment: look in you network tab, dev tools, and see if there are any failed fetches to fix..

Comment: @BenBeck Added the code in the OP. I only searched for http: WITH the colon, so I'm hoping it didn't break anything so simple. But maybe. There's ~150 instances in all the .js files.

Comment: @Searching Just looked at the Network tab. Looks like everything loaded. I'm not super familiar with it, but nothing is red or crossed out. No errors, as far as I can see except the one shown in Console.

Comment: @needalittlehelp, so I'm only speculating at this point. But I'm guessing the file you edited here is a bundle of your app including some 3rd party source code? If this file got copy/replaced on then you could have some potential issues.

Comment: @BenBeck It is. It's about 95% stock foundation.js and 5% my custom code. Any idea where to start troubleshooting?

Comment: @BenBeck Well, that was easy. It had been awhile since I worked on this. It was 100% foundation.js and my custom code was elsewhere. I replaced the foundation.js with the original, that hadn't replaced http with https and it all worked fine. Thanks for helping me think through this.

Comment: @needalittlehelp -- Ahh that would make sense. You're welcome!